# Error While Integrating Facebook Login Using Parse In Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, facebook-login

Hi in my project I am using parse to store user login, and when I am trying to integrate the Facebook login, I am getting error in my Application class in this line

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(MyApplication.this);
```

and the error is...

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "boolean com.parse.ParseAuthenticationProvider.restoreAuthentication(org.json.JSONObject)"
        at com.parse.ParseUser.synchronizeAuthData(ParseUser.java:1472)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.registerAuthenticationProvider(ParseUser.java:1525)
        at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:95)
        at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:79)
        at com.sanafoundation.sanjaym.app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:44)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1034)
```

And my Application class is

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;

    // register with parse
    ParseUtils.registerParse(this);

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    Parse.initialize(this,
            AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID,
            AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY
    );

    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(MyApplication.this);

}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

}
```

I tried adding library path in build.gradle file also, but its not working. Can someone help me?

Comment: I am also getting this issue. I actually don't get the error until I have saved some information to a user. After I do that, everytime the app runs it crashes on the ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(MyApplication.this); line, w/ the same error as you.